# Is there a native KVM utility that reports all VM data?

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a reporting tool in KVM that shows all VMs, including CPU, RAM, storage, and hopefully utilization. Does such a utility exist?

Thanks!

Comment: kvm is a pretty low-level tool, are you actually using it directly (e.g., starting your VMs by running `kvm`/`qemu` from the command line) or at you using something else like libvirt?

Comment: If you're using Libvirt or Proxmox you can even get pretty graphs of this kind of metadata.

Answer (score 0):

KVM is just the hypervisor, what you need is a management layer tool. oVirt, proxmox, openstack, even plain libvirt - they all have means of displaying this information. Any decent monitoring solution with libvirt support will also have ready dashboards.